# How to convert a normal Set[A] to a set of tuples Set[(A,Int)] in scala efficiently?

Tags: algorithm, scala, performance, set, tuples

I have a mutable set Set[A] called picks. I want to make an immutable set called set that is a tuple. Its first element is the original A from the picks set, and the second element is a int, which will be zero at first. Here is what I have

```
var set = scala.collection.mutable.Set[(A, Int)]()
for (index <- picks) yield (set += (index -> 0))
```

This code works and does what I want. It is just very slow when the sets get big. Is there a faster way to do this?

EDIT

This part of my code is also way too slow and needs work.

```
val temp = scala.collection.mutable.Set[(A, Int)]()
    for (index <- s) yield (if(index._2 != maxLies) {
      temp += (index._1 -> (index._2 + 1))
    })
```

it creates a temporary set and loops through an already define set called s which is [(A,Int)] and  checks if the int is greater than a certain number and if it is, it removes it from the set. If it is not then it adds one to the Int

Comment: `val set = picks.map(_ -> 0)`

Comment: `picks` is unchanged and still available for interrogation. To go from modified `set` to a new immutable you can `val pix = set.map(_._1).toSet`.

Comment: You're writing C code in the Scala language. I recommend spending a little time with a good FP focused tutorial as well as study of the Scala standard library.

Comment: `val x = s.collect{case (a,b) if b != maxLies => (a, b+1)}`

Answer (score 1):

i think `zipWithIndex` does what you need

```
var set = Set("a", "b", "c")
val tuples = set.zipWithIndex { case (item, index) => (item, index) } 

// ( ("a", 0), ("b", 1), ("c", 2)
```